# Downloading latest ubuntu (13.04) + downloading windows programs

Tags: 13.04

I recently downloaded a really old Ubuntu version (I forgot which one...), but it said I should download the latest version of Ubuntu to get updated security and such... So I did, I downloaded the .ISO but now I have no idea what to do... Do I put it onto a disk and restart my computer, or what?
I already tried to run the .exe but isn't that for windows only? Also... since I already ventured into .exe... How do I download windows programs onto Ubuntu?
Keep in mind... I'm kind of new to Ubuntu. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute Windows programs on forms of Linux without a platform such as WINE as they are not supported. If you have an EXE called Wubi.exe, you have an installer that installs Ubuntu from within Windows, this is not necesarily advised but it is very simple for people just starting out.

---

**For Boot Installation**

1. Burn the image onto the disk, making sure that the image is
   extracted and not simply placed on there as a single .ISO file.
2. Reboot and make sure that your disc or USB is selected as the boot media and you will be faced with the linux/ubuntu boot screen, presented with options such as "try without installing" etc.
3. Select install and follow the instructions, if you still have Windows installed, select install alongside windows or edit the partitions manually.

There is a tutorial documented [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

---

**For Wubi Installation**

Simply run the Wubi.exe file and follow the simple instructions provided by the application.

There is a tutorial documented [here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

Comment: Well, the problem is I deleted windows as I got a blue screen so now I'm only on Ubuntu

Comment: Are you just after installing Ubuntu or would you like to dual boot the two, eventually?

Comment: I don't want to use windows anymore, so I'm just after Ubuntu... But I already found the answer, you just go into update manager